# Best workflow for developing npm packages that depend on each other

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, npm, package.json

Currently we're developing two React-based applicaties, say `app-a` and `app-b` that has two dependencies we also manage. A `shared-components` package, which contains shared components, and a `shared-utilities` package which contains shared utilities between `app-a` and `app-b`. Both of these have their own full on package.json, and are included in the package.json of `app-a` and `app-b`.

**Dependencies:**

`app-a`
`|- shared-components`
`|- shared-utilities`

and

`app-b`
`|- shared-components`
`|- shared-utilities`

Each time we're developing something in for example `shared-components` that we want to use in for example `app-a` we have to perform too many steps:

1. Make `<AwesomeComponent />` in `shared-components`
2. Build files in `shared-components`.
3. Commit/push to GitHub.
4. Point dependency in package.json from `app-a` to the specific branch.
5. Run `npm install`.
6. Use the `<AwesomeComponent />`.

If we made a mistake in developing the , we need to retart from step 1. Ofcourse we can skip the commit/push and `npm install` by copying the build files to the `node_modules` folder directly, but still, this is quite a hassle everytime we're building a component.

What workflow do you guys use or any tips/advice to speed up local development here?

*Note; we're using webpack to bundle our files and babel to transpile.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want might be [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

Simply, in the `shared-components` set it up with `sudo npm link`. This creates symlinks in the global npm directories (hence the need for elevated privileges if you installed it as root).

Next all you need to do is to go into `app-a` and run `npm link shared-components` which will replace the folder in `node_modules` with a symlink.

Comment: Thanks man! This was exactly what I was looking for :-) Got some permissions errors but I'll solve those.